# There are no primary in referenced table 'x' that match referencing column foreign key ".y"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'dbo.Client_Master' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK_dbo.Client_Question_Master_dbo.Client_Master_client_id'.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

My Client_Master Model

```
 public class Client_Master
{

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Client_Id { get; set; }
    public string Client_Name { get; set; }        
    public string Client_Address { get; set; }
    public string Client_Email { get; set; }
    public string Client_Phone { get; set; }
    [DefaultValue(" ")]
    public string Client_Country { get; set; }
    [DefaultValue(" ")]
    public string Client_State { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(" ")]
    public string Client_Postcode { get; set; }        
    public bool Is_Active { get; set; }
    public long? Created_By { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Created_Date { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Business_Master")]
    public long? Business_Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Categories")]
    public long? Category_Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Categories Categories { get; set; }

    public virtual Business_Master Business_Master { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Client_Question_Master> Client_Question_Master { get; set; }



}
```

And My Client_Question_Master Modal

```
 public class Client_Question_Master
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long client_question_master_id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Client_Master")]
    public long? client_id { get; set; }

    public virtual Client_Master Client_Master { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Question_Types")]
    public long? question_type_id { get; set; }

    public virtual Question_Types Question_Types { get; set; }

    public string question { get; set; }

    public long order_no { get; set; }

    public bool isContribute { get; set; } = true;

    [ForeignKey("Section_Master")]
    public long? section_id { get; set; }

    public virtual Section_Master Section_Master { get; set; }

    public double amount { get; set; }

    public bool isActive { get; set; } = true;

    public bool isRequired { get; set; } = true;

    public bool isComment { get; set; } = true;

    public string values { get; set; } 

    public bool isRevenue { get; set; }

    public bool isStaff { get; set; }

    public bool isMarketing { get; set; }

    public DateTime created_date { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;


}
```

After add-migration during updating database it is giving me error.

Answer (score 1):

Your usage of the `ForeignKey` attribute is the wrong way round, when using a nullable foreign key.

For example you use:

```
[ForeignKey("Client_Master")]
public long? client_id { get; set; }

public virtual Client_Master Client_Master { get; set; }
```

However it should be:

```
public long? client_id { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("client_id")]
public virtual Client_Master Client_Master { get; set; }
```

You tell `EntityFramework` what property is the foreign key. This prevent it from creating a field that has the same datatype as the primary key.

Answer (score 1):

Check your edmx file.Edmx may not have that column as Primary key in another table which you are using as foreign key.